# Export to excel without server side storage

Tags: asp.net

i want to export a gridview to excel directly on da client side....without storing on the server side as I don't have write access on Web server. May be memory stream can help in this scenario. So looking for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a webpage that just displays the gridview? Or if the gridview is in a control then pop the control into an empty page. Then do something like this on that page. So if the "xls" is in the query string when the page is called, it should prompt the user to download the file. Not sure if this is what your looking for or not.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RequestStr("xls").IsNotEmpty())
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/blankmaster.master";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= somedownload.xls");
    }
}
```

This is all you would need to do to serve the web page as an excel file.

Comment: Hi mgmedick.....thanku fr ur response.....actly dere is a Web page with gridview displayed.....nd my constraint is i dnt hv write access to Web server....so the download should happen directly to client side by using memory stream.....

Comment: This should work then, because its not writing a file to the web server. Its changing the header and the content type of the web page. I believe that when you call the page and trigger this code that the page doesn't actually show. Instead it will prompt the user to download the excel file.

Comment: does the gridview populate as soon as you call the page?

Comment: Nope..its after user inputs value and clicks submit button....then gridview appears after postback.....

Comment: Okay..Thanks....It will surely help....i will try it and let u knw....Thanks for your help

Comment: yea sorry I got confused but asked a co-worker. that's literally all you should need to do to serve the page as an excel file. No dll or anything is needed, its just using the mime type.